# Проблемы с запуском Qt на CentOS 7

Tags: qt, qt5, centos, pyqt5, pyqt

Я подключаюсь удаленно к серверу по ssh и мне не нужен интерфейс от этой библиотеки. Я просто хочу обрабатывать изображения с ее помощью.

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import QGuiApplication

app = QGuiApplication([])
```

Выдает ошибку:

```
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
Could not connect to any X display.
```

Подскажите как это можно решить? Нигде не нахожу...

upd. QCoreApplication не подходит, потому что с ним невозможно использовать классы для работы с графикой вроде QFontDatabase и QImage (`QFontDatabase: Must construct a QGuiApplication before accessing QFontDatabase`)...

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72872/discussion-on-question-by-dark-byte----qt--centos-7).

Answer (score 0):

раз вам не требуется графический интерфейс пользователя, то следует создавать экземпляр класса [QCoreApplication](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html), а не [QGuiApplication](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html):

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
app = QCoreApplication([])
```

---

смежный вопрос: [How use PyQt without GUI?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30611290/4827341)

Comment: @DarkByte, формулируйте, пожалуйста, вопрос так, чтобы в нём была вся необходимая для ответа информация.

Comment: @DarkByte, будьте добры соблюдать принятые на ресурсе правила поведения. Ругаться и хамить у нас нельзя. Если помогающий вам человек дал ответ, который вам не подходит - уточните вопрос так, чтобы понять его можно было только одним способом.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб я не понимаю каких уточнений он хочет. Вопрос сформулирован максимально точно. Пусть сам правит если хочет. У него достаточно репутации чтоб это сделать.

Comment: @DarkByte, как мне кажется, ответ нужен вам, а не отвечающему. В виду этого, думаю, вам стоит в вопросе указать почему именно данный ответ вам не годится. В этом случае кто-то ещё придёт и увидит из вопроса, что имеющийся ответ вам не помог и, может быть, предложит подходящее решение. В данный момент потенциальный отвечающий беглым взглядом сможет лишь увидеть, что ответ уже есть и пройдёт мимо. Мало кто будет вчитываться в комментарии.